# Show that a certain space of banded matrices with nonnegative determinants is connected and closed

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, matrices

Let $n$ and $k$ be two positive integers, with $n \geq 2$ and $k \geq 1$. Let $l=\{{l_i}\}$ be an $nk$-dimensional positive real vector. Let $A_{n,k}(l)={(a_{i,j})}_{1 \leq i,j \leq nk}$ be the following $nk \times nk$ matrix:
\begin{equation}
a_{i,j}=
\begin{cases}
l_i&\text{if }\quad i=j,\\
-1&\text{if }\quad 1 \leq j-i \leq n-1,\\
-1&\text{if }\quad i \geq nk-n+2\ \text{ and }\ j+nk-i \leq n-1,\\
0&\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
That is,
$$
A_{n,k}(l) = \pmatrix{
l_1 & -1 & \cdots &-1 &0 &\cdots &0\\
0 & l_2 & -1 &\ddots &-1 &\ddots &\vdots\\
\vdots & 0 & l_3 &-1 &\ddots &\ddots &0\\
0 &\ddots &\ddots &\ddots &\ddots &\ddots &-1\\
-1 &0 &\ddots &\ddots &\ddots &\ddots &\vdots \\
\vdots& \ddots& \ddots&\ddots&0&l_{kn-1}&-1\\
-1 & \cdots & -1 & 0 & \cdots & 0  & l_{kn}},
$$

where the lower triangular bottom-left block has size $(n-1)\times(n-1)$.

Denote the set of $l$ that $\det(A_{n,k}(l)) \geq 0$ be $L$. I want to show $L$ is a connected and closed set. Any comment and suggestion are welcome.

Comment: The set $L$ is closed in $\Bbb R_+^{nk}$ as a preimage of a closed set $[0,\infty)$ by a continuous map from $\Bbb R_+^{nk}\to\Bbb R$, $l\mapsto\det A_{n,k}(l) $.

Comment: I guess in the last paragraph should be $A_{n,k}$ instead of $A$.